# Depricated method from_items throws error when changed to from_dict

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was looking to fix a soon to be deprIcated method `from_items` with the advised `from_dict`

```
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 50)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 50)

Test_Data = [('originating_system_id', ['CL', 'CL', 'CL', 'CL']),
             ('security_type1', ['CORP', 'CORP', 'CORP', 'CORP']),
             ('state', ['Traded', 'Covered', 'Traded Away', 'Traded']),
             ('trading_book', ['LCAAAAA', 'NUBBBBB', 'EDFGSFG', 'PDFEFGR'])
             ]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_items(Test_Data)
print(df)

  originating_system_id     security_type1        state trading_book
0                    CL               CORP       Traded      LCAAAAA
1                    CL               CORP      Covered      NUBBBBB
2                    CL               CORP  Traded Away      EDFGSFG
3                    CL               CORP       Traded      PDFEFGR
```

When I change to `from_dict` on df assignment:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(Test_Data)
```

The following line errors when I look to apply a filter:

```
m1 = ~df['trading_book'].str.startswith(tuple(prefixes))
KeyError: 'trading_book'
```

Is `from_dict` structured differently? Is there an alternative to `from_items`?

Comment: print(df.columns.tolist()) = [0,1]. Looks like it removes headers

Comment: Exactly, so removed comment ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For me working nice convert it to dictionary:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Test_Data))
#another alternative solution
#df = pd.DataFrame({a:b for a, b in Test_Data})
print(df)
  originating_system_id rbc_security_type1        state trading_book
0                    CL               CORP       Traded      LCAAAAA
1                    CL               CORP      Covered      NUBBBBB
2                    CL               CORP  Traded Away      EDFGSFG
3                    CL               CORP       Traded      PDFEFGR
```

**Detail**:

```
print(dict(Test_Data)
{'originating_system_id': ['CL', 'CL', 'CL', 'CL'], 
 'rbc_security_type1': ['CORP', 'CORP', 'CORP', 'CORP'],
 'state': ['Traded', 'Covered', 'Traded Away', 'Traded'], 
 'trading_book': ['LCAAAAA', 'NUBBBBB', 'EDFGSFG', 'PDFEFGR']
```

Comment: Hi @jezrael      {a:b for a, b in Test_Data}, what is this actually doing?

Comment: @PeterLucas - Just simplify solution, can you test it?

Comment: Yes it's on the money. Thanks